# Pandas with flask getting Nonetype for search array

Tags: pandas, flask, nonetype

I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Which I believe is because the search array is empty when the page loads, but adding a 'is not None' check before hand doesn't fix it.

```
search = []     
if search is not None:
    search = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')    
    return render_template('drugsafety.html', tables=[filtered.to_html(classes='data')], titles=['na', 'Drug List'])
```

Why wont this escape the NoneType error?

**edit**

Updated from answer below

```
searchterms = []

    search = request.values.get('searchinput')
    if search is not None:
        searchterms = search.replace(" ","").split(',') 
    else:
        searchterms == ""

    filtered = df.query ('BP.str.contains(@searchterms, na=False)', engine='python')    
    return render_template('drugsafety.html', tables=[filtered.to_html(classes='data')], titles=['na', 'Drug List'])
```

This now gives

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `search` to the empty list. That makes it not None. So it goes into the code below the `if` There you write

```
search = request.values.get('searchinput').replace(" ","").split(',')
```

This returns the `searchinput` value is there is one. If there is no such value it returns `None`. So your values have no `searchinput`.

You do not specify how the request is sent, using `POST` or `GET` method. If it is post, your form should have a text input with id `searchinput`, if it is get, the same applies or you can have a url argument named `searchinput`

Solution:
**First** get the value of the search input, **second** if it is not `None`, replace comma's and split.

Btw, for a string a check like this is preferred:

```
if search: # True if search is not none and not the empty string
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer what you have put makes sense I'm just struggling to write it. I have updated my question. In my messing about with the code it seemed to work then on restart of the page it gave 'unhashable type: List' error.

Comment: That is a completely different issue. Please create a new question for that.